# Special character encoding in aspose words

Tags: java, aspose-cells, aspose.words

I'm using aspose cells, word to treat a csv file and copy it into a Word template and finally convert it to Pdf. 
On dev env it works like a charm, how ever in production I have some letter like ö which does not appear only in production env. 
I suspected substituon or fallback issue as as there is diffrence between fonts in both pdf files, the diffrence is times new roman font, in one file it is true type Cid with encodage identity h versus true type with encodage ANSI. 
Is reinstalling the font will help? If not any alternatives?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your request. Yes, the reason of the problem is probably causes by difference in fonts in your development and production environments. Installing the same set of fonts in your production environment should fix the problem. As an alternative you can put the required fonts in a folder and specify this folder as a fonts source. 
https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words.fonts/fontsettings
If you have any further questions you can ask here or in the [forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/) - the main place for support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I checked that and fonts are same, why would times new roman is displayed true type Cid and encodage identity H and in the second just as true type and encodage ANSI ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there's any chance that fonts got corrupted because of the embedded ones in the word template??

Comment: Font embedded into the word template might be the reason of the problem, because it might be font-subset that contains only subset of glyphs. But it is difficult to say exactly without the document. You can post your question in the [forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/) and attach the files there for deeper investigation.

Comment: ANSI encoding is used for ANSI test only, if your text contains characters that are not Unicode characters (special symbol for example) then CID font with identity-h encoding is used. In this case glyphs in the font are accessed directly by their codes.

Comment: thanks you but for confidentiality reasons unfortunally I canno't share docs

Comment: It is not required to share real documents, you can remove all sensitive information from your document living only part that will allow use to reproduce the problem.